# Time series ACF PACF vs SARIMA results

Tags: time-series, arima, acf-pacf

My SARIMA gives the following result but my acf and pacf plot shows a different story. Is it because of heteroskadiscity of the model also my model has a seasonality of 365 days how do I handle it?

[image]

[image: pacf plot]

[image: acf plot]